# When is route lookup performed when a packet flows through iptables?

Tags: iptables, routing, linux-networking, ip-routing

Iptables is often illustrated using diagram
[image: diagram]

I fail to understand when route lookup (routing tables) is performed:

1. inside the "Routing Decision" grey boxes? If so, does it mean a
   packet is routed twice?
2. after "nat POSTROUTING" and not shown in
   the picture? That is my current assumption but I could not find any
   confirmation on the internet. Is there any available reference?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. See the box "Routing Decision".

Comment: Thanks - does this mean that route lookup is executed twice on a forwarded packet (once after nat PREROUTING and once before mangle POSTROUTING)? This would seem inefficient and confusing but I am ready to accept.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion with that diagram is that not all "Routing Decisions" are created equal.  The one after "nat PREROUTING" is a simple local/remote choice; if the packet's destination is local, it goes left, and if it's remote, it goes right.  The IP routing table lookup, to determine the packet's next-hop, is the decision before "mangle POSTROUTING".  I'm honestly not sure what the one after "local process" is; even loopback traffic goes through netfilter.  Perhaps it's for non-IP traffic (which doesn't go through iptables at all), but that's a wild guess.